# Get more servlet request variables using wildcards

Tags: java, servlets

I'm sorry, I come from a PHP web world.

I'm used to using a router in frameworks like Laravel to send to controllers and get parameters. I know how to get `get` and `post` parameters using servlets by routing things with the `web.xml` `servlet-mapping` and using `*` wildcards, but am unfamiliar with how to get those url wildcards with the `HttpServletRequest` variable passed through `doGet` or `doPost`.

Is there anything where I can grab the wildcards of those urls, such as, if the url was a username or a particular page I didn't want to hard code into the web.xml? I'm sure there is.

Id like to know things like what I can get in PHP's `$_SERVER` variables for reading data about the incoming request. Stuff like cookies are also needed. Can someone give me a quick pointer with Java Servlets?

EDIT:

Or maybe I should just stick the variables to where variables belong and not make "pages" out of fake variables. I'm also open to that idea as well.

My main problem is that I don't know how to get url wildcards in `doGet` or `doPost` after it's routed from web.xml, so I'd either like to know how or be told that's a stupid thing to do and not do it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [**Spring MVC**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html). With Spring Controllers you get to do URL paths like

```
@RequestMapping("/fixed/{id}/{user}")
public String getSomeData(@PathVariable("id") String id, @PathVariable("user") String user) {
...
}
```

or even

```
@RequestMapping("/{id}/**")
public void doSomething(@PathVariable("id") int id, HttpServletRequest request) {
String remainingUrl = (String) request.getAttribute(
    HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
...
}
```